# Counting words whose letters have parity condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, combinatorics-on-words

**How many words exist, such that the total number of each letter has a given parity?**

Let $N := \{1,\dots,n\}$. I regard the set $N^r$, that is, the set of all words of length $r$ with the "letters" $1$, $\dots$, $n$.

Then I choose a subset of $A \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ and regard the set $T_A$, which is defined as follows:

$T_A$ consists of all words $i = (i_1,\dots,i_r) \in N^r$, such that:

- for all $a \in A$, the letter $a$ occurs an **odd** number of times (that is, $\# \{k : i_k = a\}$ is odd).
- for all $a \in \{1,\dots,n\}\backslash A$, the letter $a$ occurs an **even** number of times.

(That is, the subset $A$ specifies which letters in a word occur in total with an odd parity.)

Is there any formula $F$, depending on $r$, $n$, and $\#A$, which gives the **cardinality** $\# T_A$ ?

---

I got a recursive formula for $F$ which leads to a difference equation in two variables (which I couldn't solve up to now with the usual methods for solving difference equations).

Since the problem is simple to explain, I hope that it remainds on a related problem which is solved yet.
It would be great if someone takes delight in it, or, at most, has an idea :-)
Thanks a lot for your time.

---

*A little example*:

Let $n = 2$, $r = 3$ and $A = \{1\}$.

Question: In how many $3$-tuples appears the entry $1$ odd times?

Answer: In $4$, since
\begin{align*}
T_A &= \{i \in N^r : 1 \text{ appears $1$ or $3$ times in $i$}\}\\
&= \{(1,2,2),(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(1,1,1)\}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your answers and your comments. Each of them is very helpful!

Caprikuarius and vonbrand, your formulas base on a generalisation of the problem, allowing also letters whose parity doesn't matter. I think that this generalisation is very helpful, many thanks.

I apologize to use my old notation: Let $n$ be the total number of letters and $r$ be the length of the words in question. Let $F(n,r,k)$ be the number of words that contain the first $k$ letters an odd number of times and the latter $n-k$ letters an even number of times.

---

First of all, I shortly repeat the trick with multinomial coefficients of vonbrand:

- $\frac12 \big((z_1 + \dots + z_n)^r + ((-z_1) + \dots + z_n)^r\big)(1,\dots,1)$ is the number of words, such that $1$ appears an **even** number of times.
- $\frac12 \big((z_1 + \dots + z_n)^r - ((-z_1) + \dots + z_n)^r\big)(1,\dots,1)$ is the number of words, such that $1$ appears an **odd** number of times.

---

Basing on this trick, I tried to use a general "symmetrisation" of these expressions. For an example, suppose $n = k = 2$. By duplicating the formula above and by setting $(-z_2)$ instead of $z_2$ in the duplicate, we get
\begin{align*}
F(2,r,2) &= \frac14 \big([(z_1 + z_2)^r - ((-z_1) + z_2)^r] - [(z_1 + (-z_2))^r - ((-z_1) + (-z_2))^r]\big)(1,\dots,1).
\end{align*}

Following this principle of nesting, we get in general

\begin{align*}
F(n,r,k) &= \frac{1}{2^n} \left[\sum_{(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{a_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot (-1)^{a_k} \, \cdot \, \big((-1)^{a_1}z_1 + \ldots + (-1)^{a_n}z_n\big)^r\right](1,\dots,1)\\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in \{0,1\}^n} (-1)^{a_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot (-1)^{a_k} \, \cdot \, \big((-1)^{a_1} + \ldots + (-1)^{a_n}\big)^r.
\end{align*}
Reformulating this formula, we finally get

> \begin{align*}
> F(n,r,k) &= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{m = 0}^k\sum_{l = 0}^{n-k} (-1)^m\binom{k}{m}\binom{n-k}{l}\, \big(n - 2(m+l)\big)^r.
> \end{align*}

The formula should be correct, as it can be proven that it meets the requirements.

---

To compare, we have $e_k = \binom{n}{k} \cdot F(n,r,k)$, where $e_k$ (cf. vonbrand) is the number of words that contain exactly $k$ letters an odd number of times.

In particular, I wonder whether this equation holds with the formula of vonbrand.

At a first glance, it seems not to be the case, since for $n = r = k = 2$, we have
$F(2,2,2) = 2$ (which is correct), but $e_2 = -8 \neq \binom{2}{2} \cdot F(2,2,2)$, where 
\begin{align*}
e_k = \sum_{m = 0}^{n}(-1)^{m - k}\binom{k}{m}\binom{n}{m}\frac{n^r - (n-2m)^r}{2}.
\end{align*}

---

The formula should also have the following recursive properties:
\begin{align*}
F(n,r+1,k) = \begin{cases}
k\cdot F(n,r,k-1) + (n-k)\cdot F(n,r,k+1), & 1 \leq k \leq n-1,\\
n\cdot F(n,r,n-1), & k = n,\\
n\cdot F(n,r,1), & k = 0.\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
This can be seen as follows: A letter which is added at the $(r+1)$-th position changes its parity. By way of example, if the parity of letter $m$ is even in a word with $r-1$ letters, then it gets odd by adding the lettern $m$ on the $(r+1)$-th position. Since there are $k$ letters in total which are odd, there are $k$ possibilities to choose $m$ as the letter whose parity was even "before".

---

Answer (score 1):

Use generating functions throughout. Call the number of characters (alphabet size) $m$, number the characters $1, \dotsc, m$, call the length of the string $n$.

First, to find out the number of words with exactly $k$ characters which appear an odd number of times, we'll use the principle of inclusion and exclusion. Following Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf) (Academic Press, 1994), call the number of words that have at least $r$ of the letters appearing an odd number of times $N_r$, and the number of words that contain exactly $t$ letters an odd number of times $e_t$. The respective generating functions are $N(z) = \sum_r N_r z^r$ and $E(z) = \sum_t e_t z^t$; they are related by $E(z) = N(z - 1)$. Thus we have:

$\begin{align*}
  e_k
    &= [z^k] E(z) \\
    &= [z^k] N(z - 1) \\
    &= [z^k] \sum_r N_r \sum_j (-1)^{r - j} \binom{r}{j} z^j \\
    &= \sum_r (-1)^{r - k} \binom{k}{r} N_r
\end{align*}$

Now, the generating function with $z_i$ counting the number of letters $i$ of a string of length $n$ is just:
$\begin{align*}
  (z_1 + z_2 + \dotsb + z_m)^n
    &= \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + \dotsb + k_m = n}
         \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, \dotsc, k_m} z_1^{k_1} z_2^{k_2} \dotsm z_m^{k_m}
\end{align*}$

The multinomial coefficient is:

$\begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, \dotsc, k_m}
    &= \frac{n!}{k_1! \, k_2! \, \dotsm \, k_m!}
\end{align*}$

Say you want only cases in which $k_1$ is odd, this gives the sum:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{\substack{k_1 + k_2 + \dotsb + k_m = n \\\\
                  k_1 \text{ odd}}}
        \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, \dotsc, k_m} z_1^{k_1} z_2^{k_2} \dotsm z_m^{k_m}
    &= \frac{1}{2}
         \left(
           \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + \dotsb + k_m = n}
             \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, \dotsc, k_m}
               z_1^{k_1} z_2^{k_2} \dotsm z_m^{k_m}
             - \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + \dotsb + k_m = n}
                 \binom{n}{k_1, k_2, \dotsc, k_m} 
                   (-z_1)^{k_1} z_2^{k_2} \dotsm z_m^{k_m}
         \right) \\
\end{align*}$

Thus, evaluating this mess at $z_1 = z_2 = \dotsb = z_m = 1$ gives you the total number of words in which letter $1$ appears an odd number of times:

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{2} ((1 + 1 + \dotsb + 1)^n - (-1 + 1 + \dotsb + 1)^n)
    &= \frac{m^n - (m - 2)^n}{2}
\end{align*}$

There are $m$ letters that could be odd, so for one letter an odd number of times is:

$\begin{align*}
\binom{m}{1} \frac{m^n - (m - 2)^n}{2}
\end{align*}$

For the general case, if any $r$ letters appear an odd number of times each, by a similar argument you get:

$\begin{align*}
  N_r
    &= \binom{m}{r} \frac{m^n - (m - 2 r)^n}{2}
\end{align*}$

Plugging this into the expression for $e_k$ above:

$\begin{align*}
  e_k
    &= \sum_r (-1)^{r - k} \binom{k}{r} N_r \\
    &= \sum_r (-1)^{r - k}
         \binom{k}{r} \binom{m}{r} \frac{m^n - (m - 2 r)^n}{2}
\end{align*}$

No much hope to simplify this much further...

Comment: @bot, sign error fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't figured out a compact solution yet, I do have a thought on how to make the recursive solution more approachable (Dynamic Programming), so I want to share it with you.

First of all, we need a 3-dimension matrix, let's call it M, and the three of its inputs dimensions are: number of even letters #EVEN, number of odd letters #ODD, and total number of letters r. Its output is the number of words that have #EVEN even letters, #ODD odd letters, and r total letters.
let denote it M[#ODD, #EVEN, r]

I will give you the base cases as examples. It is easy to tell that when we have 1 odd letter, 0 even letter, and 1, 3, 5 ... total letter, the number of combinations for words is #A (all we need to do is to select one odd letter out of #A letters). Similarly, when we have 0 odd letter, 1 even letter, and 2, 4, 6 ... total letter, the number of combination for words is n - #A (select one even letter out of n - #A).
Notations are:
M[1, 0, 1] = #A . 
M[1, 0, 3] = #A .
...
M[0, 1, 2] = n - #A . 
M[0, 1, 4] = n - #A .
...

Now, we update the matrix in this manner: each time we only increment one odd number or one even number based on the previous results. Say if we want to calculate M[a, b, r], then M[a, b, r] = $$M[a - 1, b, r - 1] \cdot \binom{r}{1} + M[a - 1, b, r - 3] \cdot \binom{r}{3} + ... + M[a, b - 1, r - 2] \cdot \binom{r}{2} + M[a, b - 1, r - 4] \cdot \binom{r}{4} + ...$$

To make a brief explanation, suppose from the previous step, we have r - k letters for the word, and now we want to add a single letter that occur k times, then all we need to do is to find k places (from the target word with a total of r places) to insert the letter.

Also, notice that there are a few infeasible places. For instance, for an arbitrary set of a, b, r, where a + 2b > r or a and r are not both even or odd, then it is impossible to find a word with length r while having a odd letters and b even letters, in this case, fill in the matrix M[a, b, r] = 0.

You can keep updating this matrix until you have all information you need for a word of length r, then you will just sum up the matrix values with third dimension equals to r: $$\#T = \Sigma_{a, b}{M[a, b, r]}$$

I am not good at combinatoric's formulae, so I can't get the exact solution. If you can code this up in a programming language, you can eventually get this problem solved. Hopefully my answer can give you an idea on how to proceed.